# Gridview Textbox doesnot maintain Enable/Disable state but maintains Text during postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox inside a gridview.
It was initially set to Disable state.
I am enabling and disabling it in javascript.
But the problem arises during the postbacks.The grid view was able to persist the textbox data but not the Enable/Disable values.During every postback it comes back disabled even when it is enabled before the postback.
I have explored around the use of hidden field to maintain the state in these scenarious but I wish there is something less tiresome... 
Can some one enlighten me on this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the code could really help but generally take off the Enable="False" from the HTML then in the Page_Load event add something like:

```
Protected void Page_Load(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         tetxBox.enabled = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the reply..but that is what I am doing right now.The issue I don't understand is how come gridview perisists the text value but not Enable/Disable state value.Gridview maintains the text without the need for statement textbox.text = "blah blah"...